# e.force:navigateToURL does not remove previous url query parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, navigation

on lightning community using napili template when you are on a page with url and query parameters e.g. https://host/path1?name=value

then one of the lightning component fires e.force:navigateToURL for a relative url the query parameters from previous URL are still there, e.g. you ask to go to /path2 then the URL becomes https://host/path2?name=value

is there a way to get rid of those query parameters? I tried to strip it from window.location.href (but without reloading the page) but after the event is fired the query parameter is back.

Comment: What happens if you set the URL param to an absolute URL?

Comment: Then it would replace the URL correctly, however I do not want to do that (not unless I can find my community URL from within the component then construct absolute path)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build an absolute URL which will remove the qs params like so:

```
$A.get("$Site.absCoreUrl") + "/path2";
```

Yes it would be nice to have an attribute on the event which would not preserve qs params.

Comment: I created a relative url and set window.location.href instead, that way I do not have to know community url (as "$Site.absCoreUrl" is not he community url)

Comment: will not work in Edge

Comment: @user682217 can you explain why it won't work?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 
 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176873/ms-edge-error-when-accessing-window-location-in-lightning-components-with-lock