# (MS Edge) Error when accessing window.location in lightning components with LockerService enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, locker-service

My lightning component (V40/SU17) errors out when accessed via MS Edge with LockerService enabled. Is there a different method of accessing the `window.location`?

**WindowLocation.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="url" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <p>{!v.url}</p>
</aura:component>
```

**WindowLocationController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.url", window.location.href);
    }
})
```

**WindowLocationDemo.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <c:WindowLocation />
</aura:application>
```

Here's the error when viewed in MS Edge

[image]

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: c:WindowLocation$controller$doInit [WeakMap.prototype.set:
>   'key' is not an object] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:WindowLocation$controller$doInit}

Comment: I am facing the same problem. When I load jquery2.2.4 in to lightning component and try to open a component page, I got this error from the jquery library, since in the library they are using windows.location. Do you have a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Just verified that this is the behavior we see too. It appears to be a bug in MS Edge. See related discussion and link to MS Edge bug.
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15249
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12112572/

Comment: I'll remove my answer, since it's incorrect. Thanks for the info!

Comment: What did you think it was originally, @sfdcfox?

Comment: @jmrjulian I thought it was a bug with LS. This answer says it's a browser bug, which makes sense.

Comment: Does anybody know any temporary workaround or any alternative way for this?

Comment: ^ bump. Could it be an issue with how redirects are implemented such that a workaround is linking to a URL in a different way?

Comment: @jmrjulian We have implemented a fix in locker service to workaround the Edge bug. The fix will be part of the Spring 18 release or a subsequent patch release to Spring 18. Let us know if this issue still persists.

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa FYI the issue still persists for our Spring '18 org using Edge 40.15063.674.0

Comment: @BrentBow Can you please provide your repro steps as a separate thread? Would be easier for us to diagnose. Please tag your thread with 'locker-service' and I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using window.location.href , you can just define an attribute in your component

```
    <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" > <aura:attribute name="url" type="String" /> <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> <p>{!v.url}</p>
<aura:attribute name ="url" type="String"/>
 </aura:component
```

>

And also add an attribute to push URL variable from your lightning app and set in your component.

```
    <aura:application >
<aura:attribute name ="url" type="String"/>
 <c:WindowLocation  url="{!v.url}/>
 </aura:application>
```

***I've used this approach to get URL parameters and instead of splitting URL from getting it using location.href. while in your case you can try to get URL using $A.get('$Resource.SLDSv2') ***

Answer (score 0):

If you use `window.location` or `location.href` or anything to do with the window `location` object, there is a good chance Lightning will throw this error back at you - `[WeakMap.prototype.set: 'key' is not an object]`.

If you wish to fetch the URL, use `document.URL`.

If you wish to set the URL (redirect), use `document.location = https://your-url.com`.

These 2 solutions for getting and fetching the URL should work in all browsers, so you do not need to do any browser / feature detection and write separate code for separate browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Use "window.document.URL" instead of "window.location".
That was the only way I could solve a similar problem.