# jQuery issue with Locker service in Summer 17 release in Microsoft Edge

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, summer-17

I have lightning component and it uses jQuery to do DOM manipulation.
I manage to get it working in chrome and firefox with jQuery 2.2.2,2.2.4 and 3.2.1. But   MS Edge is throwing error . 
[image: MS Edge issue]
I have tried jQUery 1.11.2, 2.2.2,2.2.4 and 3.2.1 but no luck.
Has anyone encountered this issue? Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: I have filed a bug on our team to investigate this: W-4146185 is the bug number. Similar issue has been reported here https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues/115

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been previously reported. [(MS Edge) Error when accessing window.location in lightning components with LockerService enabled](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176873/ms-edge-error-when-accessing-window-location-in-lightning-components-with-lock)
The cause is a MS Edge bug, we have filed an issue for the MS team. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12112572/

Comment: @balinder-singh We have implemented a workaround for this issue in Spring 18. If your org is on an instance that is already on Spring 18, please give it a week to get the fix.