# Issue with ltng:require tag in Lightning component in Summer 17 (Locker Service API 40) in IE 11

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, summer-17

I am building Lightning component in which I am using ltng tag like this:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.MyScriptResourceJs}"   />
```

But in IE 11 it throws following error in browser debugger :
Action failed: ltng:require$controller$init ['Proxy' is undefined] Callback failed: aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getComponent

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Dont use internet explorer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the issue you are facing is caused by IE11.

The root of the problem is that LockerService is now enabled by default since Summer '17 and IE11 is one of the few browsers that do not implement required security standards.

The official recommendation is to use another browser than IE11:

> IE11 doesn’t support CSP, so we recommend using other supported browsers for enhanced security.

Source:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_lightning_locker.htm

FYI: IE11 has been removed from the list of supported browsers for Lightning Experience:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: Thanks for the answer @POZ .
I will see if there is any workaround for it...
I also have issue with Microsoft edge  which is bit different :
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181961/jquery-issue-with-locker-service-in-summer-17-release-in-microsoft-edge .
Any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in ltng:require.

Locker Service is not supported in IE11 and we gracefully degrade it and let the components work in non-lockerized mode. But some recent code changes were causing ltng:require to invoke locker service routines that require Proxy support and would cause the error you reported.

This has been previously reported and a salesforce case has been logged(case no 16639381). We are fixing this in the this week's(7/5/2017 - 208.12) patch release. This will be the bug number tracking the fix W-4084212.

Comment: Thanks @Ravi   for your response.. 
Any insight on this issue : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181961/jquery-issue-with-locker-service-in-summer-17-release-in-microsoft-edge

Answer (score 0):

Definitely there are some issues with ltng:require, but ultimate workaround is to move the locker service api version back to previous version.

Setup --> Session Setting

[image]