# Highcharts not being rendered in Microsoft Edge browser | Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service, highcharts, microsoft-edge

I'm facing an issue where Highcharts report is not being loaded when opened using Microsoft edge browser. It's loading fine when opened using Google Chrome.

Here's the code:-

Component:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                           $Resource.summer17resources + '/jQuery_V1.js',
                           $Resource.highcharts + '/highcharts.js'
          )}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="isResourcesLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
    <div id="drag"></div>
    <div id="drop"></div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:-

```
({
    afterLoad : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isResourcesLoaded",true);
    }
})
```

Helper:-

```
({
    drawChart : function(component, helper) {
        if(component.isValid() && component.get("v.isResourcesLoaded") ){
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container',{
                chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Height (cm)'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Weight (kg)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        helper.navigateToReport(component);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Female',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
            [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
            [172.5, 55.2], [170.9, 54.2], [172.9, 62.5], [153.4, 42.0], [160.0, 50.0],
            [147.2, 49.8], [168.2, 49.2], [175.0, 73.2], [157.0, 47.8], [167.6, 68.8],
            [159.5, 50.6], [175.0, 82.5], [166.8, 57.2], [176.5, 87.8], [170.2, 72.8],
            [174.0, 54.5], [173.0, 59.8], [179.9, 67.3], [170.5, 67.8], [160.0, 47.0],
            [154.4, 46.2], [162.0, 55.0], [176.5, 83.0], [160.0, 54.4], [152.0, 45.8],
            [162.1, 53.6], [170.0, 73.2], [160.2, 52.1], [161.3, 67.9], [166.4, 56.6],
            [168.9, 62.3], [163.8, 58.5], [167.6, 54.5], [160.0, 50.2], [161.3, 60.3],
            [167.6, 58.3], [165.1, 56.2], [160.0, 50.2], [170.0, 72.9], [157.5, 59.8],
            [167.6, 61.0], [160.7, 69.1], [163.2, 55.9], [152.4, 46.5], [157.5, 54.3],
            [168.3, 54.8], [180.3, 60.7], [165.5, 60.0], [165.0, 62.0], [164.5, 60.3],
            [156.0, 52.7], [160.0, 74.3], [163.0, 62.0], [165.7, 73.1], [161.0, 80.0],
            [162.0, 54.7], [166.0, 53.2], [174.0, 75.7], [172.7, 61.1], [167.6, 55.7],
            [151.1, 48.7], [164.5, 52.3], [163.5, 50.0], [152.0, 59.3], [169.0, 62.5],
            [164.0, 55.7], [161.2, 54.8], [155.0, 45.9], [170.0, 70.6], [176.2, 67.2],
            [170.0, 69.4], [162.5, 58.2], [170.3, 64.8], [164.1, 71.6], [169.5, 52.8],
            [163.2, 59.8], [154.5, 49.0], [159.8, 50.0], [173.2, 69.2], [170.0, 55.9],
            [161.4, 63.4], [169.0, 58.2], [166.2, 58.6], [159.4, 45.7], [162.5, 52.2],
            [159.0, 48.6], [162.8, 57.8], [159.0, 55.6], [179.8, 66.8], [162.9, 59.4],
            [161.0, 53.6], [151.1, 73.2], [168.2, 53.4], [168.9, 69.0], [173.2, 58.4],
            [171.8, 56.2], [178.0, 70.6], [164.3, 59.8], [163.0, 72.0], [168.5, 65.2],
            [166.8, 56.6], [172.7, 105.2], [163.5, 51.8], [169.4, 63.4], [167.8, 59.0],
            [159.5, 47.6], [167.6, 63.0], [161.2, 55.2], [160.0, 45.0], [163.2, 54.0],
            [162.2, 50.2], [161.3, 60.2], [149.5, 44.8], [157.5, 58.8], [163.2, 56.4],
            [172.7, 62.0], [155.0, 49.2], [156.5, 67.2], [164.0, 53.8], [160.9, 54.4],
            [162.8, 58.0], [167.0, 59.8], [160.0, 54.8], [160.0, 43.2], [168.9, 60.5],
            [158.2, 46.4], [156.0, 64.4], [160.0, 48.8], [167.1, 62.2], [158.0, 55.5],
            [167.6, 57.8], [156.0, 54.6], [162.1, 59.2], [173.4, 52.7], [159.8, 53.2],
            [170.5, 64.5], [159.2, 51.8], [157.5, 56.0], [161.3, 63.6], [162.6, 63.2],
            [160.0, 59.5], [168.9, 56.8], [165.1, 64.1], [162.6, 50.0], [165.1, 72.3],
            [166.4, 55.0], [160.0, 55.9], [152.4, 60.4], [170.2, 69.1], [162.6, 84.5],
            [170.2, 55.9], [158.8, 55.5], [172.7, 69.5], [167.6, 76.4], [162.6, 61.4],
            [167.6, 65.9], [156.2, 58.6], [175.2, 66.8], [172.1, 56.6], [162.6, 58.6],
            [160.0, 55.9], [165.1, 59.1], [182.9, 81.8], [166.4, 70.7], [165.1, 56.8],
            [177.8, 60.0], [165.1, 58.2], [175.3, 72.7], [154.9, 54.1], [158.8, 49.1],
            [172.7, 75.9], [168.9, 55.0], [161.3, 57.3], [167.6, 55.0], [165.1, 65.5],
            [175.3, 65.5], [157.5, 48.6], [163.8, 58.6], [167.6, 63.6], [165.1, 55.2],
            [165.1, 62.7], [168.9, 56.6], [162.6, 53.9], [164.5, 63.2], [176.5, 73.6],
            [168.9, 62.0], [175.3, 63.6], [159.4, 53.2], [160.0, 53.4], [170.2, 55.0],
            [162.6, 70.5], [167.6, 54.5], [162.6, 54.5], [160.7, 55.9], [160.0, 59.0],
            [157.5, 63.6], [162.6, 54.5], [152.4, 47.3], [170.2, 67.7], [165.1, 80.9],
            [172.7, 70.5], [165.1, 60.9], [170.2, 63.6], [170.2, 54.5], [170.2, 59.1],
            [161.3, 70.5], [167.6, 52.7], [167.6, 62.7], [165.1, 86.3], [162.6, 66.4],
            [152.4, 67.3], [168.9, 63.0], [170.2, 73.6], [175.2, 62.3], [175.2, 57.7],
            [160.0, 55.4], [165.1, 104.1], [174.0, 55.5], [170.2, 77.3], [160.0, 80.5],
            [167.6, 64.5], [167.6, 72.3], [167.6, 61.4], [154.9, 58.2], [162.6, 81.8],
            [175.3, 63.6], [171.4, 53.4], [157.5, 54.5], [165.1, 53.6], [160.0, 60.0],
            [174.0, 73.6], [162.6, 61.4], [174.0, 55.5], [162.6, 63.6], [161.3, 60.9],
            [156.2, 60.0], [149.9, 46.8], [169.5, 57.3], [160.0, 64.1], [175.3, 63.6],
            [169.5, 67.3], [160.0, 75.5], [172.7, 68.2], [162.6, 61.4], [157.5, 76.8],
            [176.5, 71.8], [164.4, 55.5], [160.7, 48.6], [174.0, 66.4], [163.8, 67.3]]

    }, {
        name: 'Male',
        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
        data: [[174.0, 65.6], [175.3, 71.8], [193.5, 80.7], [186.5, 72.6], [187.2, 78.8],
            [181.5, 74.8], [184.0, 86.4], [184.5, 78.4], [175.0, 62.0], [184.0, 81.6],
            [180.0, 76.6], [177.8, 83.6], [192.0, 90.0], [176.0, 74.6], [174.0, 71.0],
            [184.0, 79.6], [192.7, 93.8], [171.5, 70.0], [173.0, 72.4], [176.0, 85.9],
            [176.0, 78.8], [180.5, 77.8], [172.7, 66.2], [176.0, 86.4], [173.5, 81.8],
            [178.0, 89.6], [180.3, 82.8], [180.3, 76.4], [164.5, 63.2], [173.0, 60.9],
            [183.5, 74.8], [175.5, 70.0], [188.0, 72.4], [189.2, 84.1], [172.8, 69.1],
            [170.0, 59.5], [182.0, 67.2], [170.0, 61.3], [177.8, 68.6], [184.2, 80.1],
            [186.7, 87.8], [171.4, 84.7], [172.7, 73.4], [175.3, 72.1], [180.3, 82.6],
            [182.9, 88.7], [188.0, 84.1], [177.2, 94.1], [172.1, 74.9], [167.0, 59.1],
            [169.5, 75.6], [174.0, 86.2], [172.7, 75.3], [182.2, 87.1], [164.1, 55.2],
            [163.0, 57.0], [171.5, 61.4], [184.2, 76.8], [174.0, 86.8], [174.0, 72.2],
            [177.0, 71.6], [186.0, 84.8], [167.0, 68.2], [171.8, 66.1], [182.0, 72.0],
            [167.0, 64.6], [177.8, 74.8], [164.5, 70.0], [192.0, 101.6], [175.5, 63.2],
            [171.2, 79.1], [181.6, 78.9], [167.4, 67.7], [181.1, 66.0], [177.0, 68.2],
            [174.5, 63.9], [177.5, 72.0], [170.5, 56.8], [182.4, 74.5], [197.1, 90.9],
            [180.1, 93.0], [175.5, 80.9], [180.6, 72.7], [184.4, 68.0], [175.5, 70.9],
            [180.6, 72.5], [177.0, 72.5], [177.1, 83.4], [181.6, 75.5], [176.5, 73.0],
            [175.0, 70.2], [174.0, 73.4], [165.1, 70.5], [177.0, 68.9], [192.0, 102.3],
            [176.5, 68.4], [169.4, 65.9], [182.1, 75.7], [179.8, 84.5], [175.3, 87.7],
            [184.9, 86.4], [177.3, 73.2], [167.4, 53.9], [178.1, 72.0], [168.9, 55.5],
            [157.2, 58.4], [180.3, 83.2], [170.2, 72.7], [177.8, 64.1], [172.7, 72.3],
            [165.1, 65.0], [186.7, 86.4], [165.1, 65.0], [174.0, 88.6], [175.3, 84.1],
            [185.4, 66.8], [177.8, 75.5], [180.3, 93.2], [180.3, 82.7], [177.8, 58.0],
            [177.8, 79.5], [177.8, 78.6], [177.8, 71.8], [177.8, 116.4], [163.8, 72.2],
            [188.0, 83.6], [198.1, 85.5], [175.3, 90.9], [166.4, 85.9], [190.5, 89.1],
            [166.4, 75.0], [177.8, 77.7], [179.7, 86.4], [172.7, 90.9], [190.5, 73.6],
            [185.4, 76.4], [168.9, 69.1], [167.6, 84.5], [175.3, 64.5], [170.2, 69.1],
            [190.5, 108.6], [177.8, 86.4], [190.5, 80.9], [177.8, 87.7], [184.2, 94.5],
            [176.5, 80.2], [177.8, 72.0], [180.3, 71.4], [171.4, 72.7], [172.7, 84.1],
            [172.7, 76.8], [177.8, 63.6], [177.8, 80.9], [182.9, 80.9], [170.2, 85.5],
            [167.6, 68.6], [175.3, 67.7], [165.1, 66.4], [185.4, 102.3], [181.6, 70.5],
            [172.7, 95.9], [190.5, 84.1], [179.1, 87.3], [175.3, 71.8], [170.2, 65.9],
            [193.0, 95.9], [171.4, 91.4], [177.8, 81.8], [177.8, 96.8], [167.6, 69.1],
            [167.6, 82.7], [180.3, 75.5], [182.9, 79.5], [176.5, 73.6], [186.7, 91.8],
            [188.0, 84.1], [188.0, 85.9], [177.8, 81.8], [174.0, 82.5], [177.8, 80.5],
            [171.4, 70.0], [185.4, 81.8], [185.4, 84.1], [188.0, 90.5], [188.0, 91.4],
            [182.9, 89.1], [176.5, 85.0], [175.3, 69.1], [175.3, 73.6], [188.0, 80.5],
            [188.0, 82.7], [175.3, 86.4], [170.5, 67.7], [179.1, 92.7], [177.8, 93.6],
            [175.3, 70.9], [182.9, 75.0], [170.8, 93.2], [188.0, 93.2], [180.3, 77.7],
            [177.8, 61.4], [185.4, 94.1], [168.9, 75.0], [185.4, 83.6], [180.3, 85.5],
            [174.0, 73.9], [167.6, 66.8], [182.9, 87.3], [160.0, 72.3], [180.3, 88.6],
            [167.6, 75.5], [186.7, 101.4], [175.3, 91.1], [175.3, 67.3], [175.9, 77.7],
            [175.3, 81.8], [179.1, 75.5], [181.6, 84.5], [177.8, 76.6], [182.9, 85.0],
            [177.8, 102.5], [184.2, 77.3], [179.1, 71.8], [176.5, 87.9], [188.0, 94.3],
            [174.0, 70.9], [167.6, 64.5], [170.2, 77.3], [167.6, 72.3], [188.0, 87.3],
            [174.0, 80.0], [176.5, 82.3], [180.3, 73.6], [167.6, 74.1], [188.0, 85.9],
            [180.3, 73.2], [167.6, 76.3], [183.0, 65.9], [183.0, 90.9], [179.1, 89.1],
            [170.2, 62.3], [177.8, 82.7], [179.1, 79.1], [190.5, 98.2], [177.8, 84.1],
            [180.3, 83.2], [180.3, 83.2]]
    }]

            });
        }
    },
    navigateToReport: function(component) {
        var chartEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");

        chartEvent.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:middlecomponent",          
        });
        chartEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Renderer:-

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
        helper.drawChart(component, helper);
    },
    rerender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superRerender();       
        helper.drawChart(component, helper);
    }
})
```

I'm using jQuery version 2.2.4 and 
Highcharts version 5.0.9 (https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.9/highcharts.src.js)

**Also, I've created an unmanaged package for making it easy to replicate the issue. Here's the link to install the same:- 
https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tB00000009ZJZ**

---

The error that displays in Microsoft Edge is as follows:

> [WeakMap.prototype.set: 'key' is not an object]
>
> Aa()@https://redacted.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/aura_prod.js:719:102
>
> Xc()@https://redacted.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/aura_prod.js:715:56
>
> location.get()@https://redacted.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/aura_prod.js:704:90
>
> Anonymous function (Unknown script()@code:7955:1
>
> Anonymous function (Unknown script()@code:36:3
>
> Anonymous function (Unknown script()@code:17:2
>
> $globalEvalIIFE$ (Unknown script()@code:1:75
>
> safeEval()@https://redacted.lightning.force.com/auraFW/resources/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/lockerservice/safeEval.html?id=Custom:117:11
>
> value()@https://redacted.lightning.force.com/auraFW/resources/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/lockerservice/safeEval.html?id=Custom:126:23

Comment: I added the "Technical Stuff" to your answer in hopes that it'll shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Seems to be related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176873/ms-edge-error-when-accessing-window-location-in-lightning-components-with-lock

Answer (score 1):

kindly check out this discussion here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15249 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12112572/
https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/2983

It is a known issue for quite some time.